# Are there subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ with a finite number of upper-bounds?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

> Consider the poset $(\mathbb{Q}, \leq)$. Is there a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ with a finite number of elements that are upper-bounds?

I tried to prove this as follows:

Suppose $K \subset \mathbb{Q}$, if $x \in K$ then $x+1 \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $x+2 \in \mathbb{Q}$ and so goes. This implies that for any subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ there is an infinite number of elements that are upper-bounds.

Comment: You can have subsets of $\Bbb Q$ with **no** upper bounds.

Comment: i think i'm not getting the definition of upperbounds then, if k={1} isn't j={2, 3...} upperbound of k since k ⊂ Q and J ⊂ Q?

Comment: upper-bounds of what?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take $\mathbb{Q}$. It has no upper bounds. More generally, you can take any subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ that is unbounded above (there are many).